# Webview - is it possible to update only a portion of the view?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webview, vscode-extensions

In the Webview extensions guide (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview), it states that in order to update the view, one needs to set the entire view (via `panel.webview.html`).  Is it possible to only update a portion of the view, without having to updating the entire view?

I'd like to have a timer running (`setInterval()`) and either have an element blink on/off, or change an element's color (maybe toggle back and forth between white and red).

If this were an HTML page, I would use a CSS selector to find the element, and then either a) change its visibility, or b) add and remove classes applied to the element, but I haven't found a means to access the elements which were rendered.

Comment: you can run JS inside the Webview, and perform [message passing](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#scripts-and-message-passing)

Comment: Thanks @rioV8, that was exactly what I was looking for.  (and I completely missed it when I was reading up on Webviews)